# tinyMCE Editor removes custom tags in div elements

Tags: tinymce, custom-tag

I need to add some custom tags into tinyMCE. It's ok if they are in body tag alone, but if I put them into the div tags then editor removes it. Here is the example:

I need to add "unsubthis" tag, so I've got this configuration file

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "textareas",
  verify_html : false,
  skin: "o2k7",
  theme: "advanced",
  entity_encoding: "raw",
  plugins: "fullpage,safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
  theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
  theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
  theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
  theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
  theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",      
  custom_elements: "unsubthis",
  valid_children: "+div[unsubthis]",
  extended_valid_elements: "unsubthis"
});
```

If I open the editor and put into HTML this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document Title 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <unsubthis></unsubthis>
</body>
</html>
```

and Update then everything is fine and if I look into the HTML, code looks same. Problem comes if I try put into HTML this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document Title 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <unsubthis></unsubthis>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then unsubthis will be stripped out after update and I'll get this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Document Title 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem occurs only if the unsubthis tag is empty, how can I fix it?

I'm currently using 3.5.6 version.

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle for this please? : fiddle.tinymce.com

Comment: Yes, of course http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cTbaab

Comment: +1 thx for the fiddle. the unsubthis element does not get removed: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gTbaab

Comment: As I said before - if unsubthis has some content, then it's OK. But I need unsubthis tag empty as it is in my example (I'm replacing this tag with some standard html content later).

Comment: the tag is still there even without content as it should be (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/gTbaab/2)

Comment: Yes, but if you delete text from div then it'll disappear. I just need to have only <div><unsubthis></unsubthis></div> (as I said, put something meaningfull later instead of unsubthis).

Comment: hmm, that is right and it should not be this way - i can remember a bug report for this (maybe it is still not fixed)

Comment: So there is not error in my code. OK then, I'll try some other solution for my problem. Thank you.